# How to use PHP display data of last insert row of a specific column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in database with 2 columns, id(auto increment) and name.

```
id|name
--|----
1 |John
2 |Jeff
3 |Jack
```

I wish to show the last insert name in my webpage so I can `echo "The last person is $last_name";`

I try retrieve the data by using following command, but it shows nothing.

```
$last_name = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT name FROM namelist ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1')
```

Someone please help?
Thank you.

Comment: u can use `mysqli_insert_id($conn)` after INSERT share the full code, where you are using fetch_row function, and also run this query in your PHP MYADMIN `SELECT name FROM namelist ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: does this work when executed against mysql command line interface?

Comment: @Ivan Yes, the `SELECT` command work in mysql CLI

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

**If Procedural**

```
$query = "INSERT INTO myCity VALUES (NULL, 'Stuttgart', 'DEU', 'Stuttgart', 617000)";
mysqli_query($conn, $query);
mysqli_insert_id($conn)
```

**If Object oriented**

```
$query = "INSERT INTO myCity VALUES (NULL, 'Stuttgart', 'DEU', 'Stuttgart', 617000)";
$mysqli->query($query);
$mysqli->insert_id
```

**For more...** http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Comment: Hi, sorry that I am not understand why i should enter the `$query` command line? And isn't the `mysqli_insert_id()` returns the last id but not the last `name`? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
$last_name = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT name FROM namelist ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1')

if (mysqli_num_rows($last_name) > 0) {
// output data of row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($last_name)) {
        echo "Name: " . $row["name"];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: do a `print_r($row)`  see if there is  any result also run that query in phpmyadmin to see if there are any results

Answer (score -1):

```
mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT name FROM namelist ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1')
```